How to determine if a directed edge is visible? What does visibility tell us?

Both of the above PAGs (Partial Ancestral Graph) are generated using the FCI (Fast Causal Inference) algorithm under identical conditions, the only difference being that the one on the right is generated after excluding variable 5 from the dataset.

Can someone please help me determine whether the directed edge between 9 and 11 in the right PAG is visible and explain the steps involved in this analysis?
What does the above analysis imply about the possible existence of unmeasured confounders of 9 and 11 and why?
Does the right PAG say that 9 is a parent or an ancestor of 11? Please explain.


Causal Inference with Ancestral Graphs
Finally, any guidance on how a directed edge can be tested for visibility in a software package in Python or R would be most welcome. I heard that it can be done in Tetrad but I don’t have any experience with it as of now.
Thank you
close up of right PAG below:

close up of left PAG below:


Please provide demarcations of acronyms

Good point; I just did

I added close-ups of the 2 graphs

Have you tried to falsify the graphs?  (for example by using a methodology akin to Eulig et al. (2023).

I have not. I am not familiar with it. Can you help understand how falsifying the graph would help with determining visibility of a directed edge?


The edge $(9)\rightarrow(11)$ is indeed visible in the right PAG. This is because $(1)$ fulfills the condition for a valid $C$, as it is not adjacent to $(11)$, and $(1)\rightarrow(9)$ is present in the PAG.

Lemma 10 applies only to invisible edges. However, according to the contraposition of Lemma 9, if the edge $(9)\rightarrow(11)$ is visible, then in every DAG represented by the MAG in question, there are no inducing paths between $(9)$ and $(11)$ relative to latent variables entering $(9)$. This does not eliminate the possibility of latent confounding. For instance, consider that in the true DAG there is a latent variable $L_1$ such that:


$$
(11)\leftarrow (9)\leftarrow L_1\leftarrow (5)\rightarrow (11)
$$
Then:

There is an inducing path between $(5)$ and $(9)$ relative to $L_1$, and $(5)$ is ancestor of $(9)$.
There is an inducing path between $(5)$ and $(11)$ relative to $L_1$, and $(5)$ is ancestor of $(11)$.
These two statements justify why both $(5)\rightarrow(9)$ and $(5)\rightarrow(11)$ appear in the left PAG.
But, there are no inducing paths between $(9)$ and $(11)$ relative to the latent variables entering $(9)$, which is only $L_1$ here. This is, $(9)\leftarrow L_1\leftarrow (5)\rightarrow (11)$ is not an inducing path relative to $L_1$ because $(5)$ is not a collider on this path.
However, there is latent confounding because both $L_1$ and $(5)$ are latent in the right PAG.
While it's true that, by the contrapositive of Lemma 9, visibility rules out the existence of a latent variable $K$ such that $(9)\leftarrow K\rightarrow (11)$, which is typically considered a "confounder", there are more confounding structures than this one.
Moreover, the edge $(5)\rightarrow(11)$ on the left PAG is in fact invisible, so by Lemma 10, there might be a latent confounder $L_2$ such that $(5)\leftarrow L_2 \rightarrow(11)$. Therefore, the structure might look like:

$$
(11)\leftarrow (9)\leftarrow L_1\leftarrow (5)\leftarrow L_2 \rightarrow(11)
$$

The edge $(9)\rightarrow(11)$ in the right PAG indicates that all MAGs in the Markov-equivalent class represented by the PAG agree on the presence and direction of this edge. This means that $(9)$ is an ancestor of $(11)$ and there is an inducing path relative to some latent $L$ (just like the one above); or $(9)$ is a parent of $(11)$ and there is no confounder between.

Therefore, things we can say for sure:

$(9)$ is an ancestor of $(11)$.
There is no latent confounding of the form $(9)\leftarrow K\rightarrow (11)$.

Things that might be:

$(9)$ is a parent of $(11)$.
Confounding of the form $(9)\leftarrow L_1\leftarrow (5)\leftarrow L_2 \rightarrow(11)$ or $(9)\leftarrow (5)\leftarrow L_2 \rightarrow(11)$ or maybe other confounding structures.


#1 was the heart of the question; perfect! But #2 is just as important as we want to draw the right conclusion from our finding that the path is visible

+1: on #1) great; thank you. on #2) I thought visibility of a directed edge implies the absence of a confounder of the endpoints #3) can you please expand on what an inducing path is?

I edited my previous answer to make it more detailed. An inducing path between $A$ and $B$ relative to $L$ is a path between $A$ and $B$ where every intermediate node that is not in $L$ is a collider, and every collider on the path is an ancestor of $A$ or $B$.

First of all, thank you. An eye-opening answer. Secondly, may I ask if you've seen this material covered any other place than in the referenced paper by Jiji Zhang? Any other resources you'd recommend? In particular I'd love to see applications of this theory; a few examples would be nice; the paper lacks any examples/applications of the theory.

Yes. You can check the references in this presentation: http://www.stat.ucla.edu/~zhou/courses/Stats212_Latent.pdf

Great resource! Thank you.

Caveat: I am fairly familiar with DAGs and CPDAGs, but not particularly so with PAGs.
Q1
I know you are asking for an analysis with expectation, but my feeling is that with a graph as complex as yours this is going to be a rather tedious task for anyone as much as it seems to be for you.
May I therefore suggest you use the visibleEdge function implemented in the R pakcage pcalg? You can find the documentation here.
Q2
My impression is that there is something of a contradiction here - there seems to be an unmeasured confounder in $5$, but the directed edge suggest there is none. It might be worth looking at ($5$, $9$, $11$) in isolation and examining (e.g. plotting) their pairwise relationships. Perhaps a different independence test might suit the data better?
Edit for future readers: There is indeed no contradiction - a directed edge suggested by FCI does not exclude the possibility of additional unmeasured confounding.
Q3
If I see correctly, the edge from $9$ to $11$ is a simple directed edge, meaning that there is no uncertainty about the direction. This means $9$ is a parent of $11$ (which also makes it an ancestor).

+1: Thank you for pointing me to pcalg's implementation of visibleEdge. While PC assumes that the DAG is known, which is in contrast to FCI which allows unmeasured confounders, this would still be insightful. I also initially thought it was a contradiction. It turns out there isn't a contradiction here. As the FCI authors themselves explain in Tetrad a directed edge means "a directed edge from A to B: A is a cause of B; it may be a direct or indirect cause that may include other measured variables. Also, there may be an unmeasured confounder of A and B".

A directed edge from A to B really only says that B does not cause A. That is the biggest thing we learn from it.

I learned DAGs from Pearl's "Causal Inference in Statistics: A Primer". In it, every DAG is assumed to be complete (so we are assuming away the possibility of unmeasured confounders). Like you I was interpreting a directed edge from A to B as saying unambiguously that A causes B and that there is no unmeasured confounder between A and B (by assumption that the DAG is complete). However, with FCI we allow the possibility of unmeasured confounders, the outputs are PAGs as opposed to DAGs, and here, somewhat surprisingly, a directed edge has a slightly different interpretation.

I asked about parent vs. ancestor because I suspect that we can only ever establish that a variable is an ancestor of another as opposed to a parent. I'd love to hear what others have to say about this.

Re parent vs. ancestor: I agree in principle, every edge could contain additional mediators that aren't explicitly modeled as separate variables. However, the distinction is still meaningful among the variables that are modeled explicitly. So I take "parent" to refer to the fact that it is a parent as far as the variables in question (and not some other unmodeled ones) are concerned.
